# Frequency response of a filter - fft vs. freqz

Tags: matlab, fft, filters

I have designed my filter using `firhalfband(N,Fo,A)`, which gives me the filter coefficients. Then I try to see the frequency response of it. I use these two function: `fft`, and `freqz`, but they are giving me different result in my figure, why is that? I wonder how these two MATLAB functions operate when taking the frequency response of a signal. I am expecting them to be the same.

Thank you

Comment: There is no need to duplicate posts on the same topic. Here is [**answer**](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/16888/8202) that should help you. Basically output from the `fft` must be scaled and represented properly.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the filter coefficients, freqz is the way to go - the various optional input arguments and the expected outputs are documented in MATLAB which you can see using help freqz. Snippets given below:

" freqz Digital filter frequency response.
    [H,W] = freqz(B,A,N) returns the N-point complex frequency response
    vector H and the N-point frequency vector W in radians/sample of
    the filter:

[H,F] = freqz(B,A,N,Fs) and [H,F] = freqz(B,A,N,'whole',Fs) return 
    frequency vector F (in Hz), where Fs is the sampling frequency (in Hz).  "

If you have filter's impulse response - which will be different from the filter coefficients - you can use it to find the frequency response of the filter using the FFT.

Comment: Actually it is an FIR filter not an IIR,which  means the filter coeffs are the filter impulse responce.Thanks though.

Comment: Then it should match with the result through the FFT if you apply it and interpret it properly,  I thought you were talking about a general filter which has both FIR and IIR components.  Thanks though for understanding what I meant.