# Difference between $\tt freqz()$ and $\tt plot(abs(fft()))$ in MATLAB

Tags: frequency-response, digital-filters

I've plotted the response of a high-pass filter `x=[1 -1]`;

`freqz(x)` gave me

[image]

where as the magnitude plot for the `fft` gave me

[image]

Why are the two plots different? Both are frequency responses, then why are my plots are diffferent. What does `freqz()` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You calculating FFT only from two samples. You need to pad your impulse response with zeros to get a valid result. So in MATLAB that would be:

```
N = 1024; % Number of points to evaluate at
% Create the vector of angular frequencies at one more point.
% Filter itself
b=[1,-1];
[h_f, w_f] = freqz(b, 1);
figure
grid on
hold on
plot(w_f, abs(h_f), 'or') % MATLAB
h = [b, zeros(1,N-2)];
HH = abs(fft(h));
HH = HH(1:length(w_f));
plot(w_f, HH); % Manual calculation
legend({'MATLAB freqz', 'Manual'})
```

As you can see it matches first and last value from fft you calculated. Please keep in mind that it is shown in linear - not dB scale.

[image]

For more info you can see my [**previous answer**](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/16888/8202).

Comment: Another important point is that invoking 'freqz()' without any specified output argument plots the magnitude in dB (as seen in the top plot of the OP).

Comment: Sure thing, but I assumed he already knew about that. It is worth to update the answer.

Comment: I was not aware that freqz() plots the  answer in dB scale. Thanks for your answer. I'll crosscheck while asking the next question @jojek

Comment: It is obviously mentioned on y axis  label. Good luck!