# Amplitude transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, amplitude

Given a LTI-system  $$y[n]=x[n]-2x[n-1]+y[n-1]- \frac{8}{9}y[n-2]$$

The transfer function $H(z)$ is:
$$H(z) = \frac{1-2z^{-1}}{1-z^{-1}+ \frac{8}{9} z^{-2}} $$

How do I calculate the amplitude transfer function so I can plot a Bode diagram like this? (in hand, not in MATLAB)

[image]

I thought that I should substitue $z=e^{j\omega}$ in $H(z)$, but it doesn't seem to be right. I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Your method is right. Just plug $z=e^{j\omega}$ into the (stable) system's Transfer function $H(z)$. Then you should simplify the expressions, then compute the magnitude of it and insert into $20 \log_{10}(\cdot)$

Comment: It might also be useful to recall Euler's formula $\text{e}^{j \omega} = \cos(\omega) + j \sin(\omega)$ for computing the the response.

Comment: possible dup of [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16885/how-do-i-manually-plot-the-frequency-response-of-a-bandpass-butterworth-filter-i/).  i have an answer that takes it a little different in that it has better numerical properties for low frequency and is simplified to as simple as it can get for a biquad (which this is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many algebraic paths to get into the required expression some of them being long and tedious, while the others being shorter with a carefully choosen route.

Given :
$$H(z) = \frac{ 1 - 2z^{-1} }{1 - z^{-1} + \frac{8}{9}z^{-2} }$$

To evaluate the corresponding **Bode-Plot**, by hand, we need to first derive the expression called as the **Frequency Spectrum Magnitude** $\lvert H(e^{j\omega})\rvert$ of $H(z)$, provided that the system is **stable** (i.e.all **poles** of $H(z)$ inside unit circle) And then compute:

$$20\log_{10}\left(\lvert H(e^{j\omega})\rvert\right),$$ 
to get the Magnitude in **dB scale**.

Let's proceed into the first step and plug $e^{j\omega}$ into $H(z)$ to get Frequency Response:
$$H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{ 1 - 2e^{-j\omega} }{1 - e^{-j\omega} + \frac{8}{9}e^{-2j\omega} }$$

As this is a **complex** valued rational fraction expression, it is equal to:
$$H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{P(e^{j\omega})}{Q(e^{j\omega})}$$

And from complex algebra, the magnitude of $H(e^{j\omega})$ is equivalent to:
$$ \lvert H(e^{j\omega})\rvert = \frac{\lvert P(e^{j\omega})\rvert}{\lvert Q(e^{j\omega})\rvert}$$

Hence we need to compute the **absolute values** of the numerator and denumerator expressions, where the absolute value of a complex number is understood as: $$z=a+jb \implies \lvert z\rvert=(a^2+b^2)^{0.5}$$

Lets elaborate the **Numerator**:
\begin{align}
P(e^{j\omega}) &= 1 - 2e^{-j\omega} = \left(1-2\cos(\omega)\right) + j\left(2\sin(\omega)\right)\\
\lvert P(e^{j\omega})\rvert &= \left[\left(1-2\cos(\omega)\right)^2 + \left(2\sin(\omega)\right)^2\right]^{0.5}\\
\lvert P(e^{j\omega})\rvert &= \left[1+4\cos^2(\omega)-4\cos(\omega) + 4\sin^2(\omega)\right]^{0.5}\\
\lvert P(e^{j\omega})\rvert &= \left[5-4\cos(\omega)\right]^{0.5}\\
\end{align}

Also elaborate the **Denumerator** (**Denominator** I mean!):
\begin{align}
Q(e^{j\omega}) &= 1 - e^{-j\omega} + \frac 89 e^{-2j\omega} = e^{-j\omega} \left(e^{j\omega} - 1 + \frac 89 e^{-j\omega}\right)\\
\lvert Q(e^{j\omega})\rvert&=\lvert e^{-j\omega}\rvert\cdot \bigg\lvert \left(e^{j\omega} - 1 + \frac 89 e^{-j\omega}\right)\bigg\rvert\\
\lvert Q(e^{j\omega})\rvert&=\bigg\lvert \left(e^{j\omega} - 1 + \frac 89 e^{-j\omega}\right)\bigg\rvert\\
\lvert Q(e^{j\omega})\rvert&=\left[\left(\cos(\omega) - 1 + \frac 89 \cos(\omega)\right)^2 + \left(\sin(\omega) - \frac 89\sin(\omega)\right)^2\right]^{0.5}\\
\lvert Q(e^{j\omega})\rvert&=\left[\left(\frac{17}{9}\cos(\omega) - 1\right)^2 + \left(\frac 19 \sin(\omega)\right)^2\right]^{0.5}\\
\end{align}

As there seems no more useful simplifications, we can deduce $\lvert H(e^{j\omega})\rvert$ as:
$$\lvert H(e^{j\omega})\lvert = \frac{\left[5-4\cos(\omega)\right]^{0.5}}{\left[\left(\frac{17}{9}\cos(\omega) - 1\right)^2 + \left(\frac 19\sin(\omega)\right)^2\right]^{0.5}}$$

The Bode plot takes the logarithm of this to produce the graph:
$$\begin{align} \lvert H(e^{j\omega})\rvert_\text{dB} & \triangleq 20 \log_{10}\left(\lvert H(e^{j\omega})\rvert\right) \\
& = 20 \log_{10}\left(\frac{\left[5-4\cos(\omega)\right]^{0.5}}{\left[\left(\frac{17}{9}\cos(\omega) - 1\right)^2 + \left(\frac 19\sin(\omega)\right)^2\right]^{0.5}}\right)\\ 
& = 10 \log_{10}\left(\frac{5-4\cos(\omega)}{\left(\frac{17}{9}\cos(\omega) - 1\right)^2 + \left(\frac 19\sin(\omega)\right)^2}\right) \\ 
& = 10 \log_{10}\left(5-4\cos(\omega)\right) - 10 \log_{10}\left(\left(\tfrac{17}{9}\cos(\omega) - 1\right)^2 + \left(\tfrac 19\sin(\omega)\right)^2\right)\\ 
\end{align}$$

Which produces the same graph when compared with `freqz([1 -2],[1 -1 8/9])` function of MATLAB to produce discrete time frequency response plot, for a **linear frequency axis**. In discrete time it is customary to use linear frequency axis rather than a logarithmic one as usual in continuous time Bode-Plots.

Comment: i love *"**Denumerator**"*.  i also did *some* simplification of the last dB equations.  that "\big(" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! If i want to find and sketch the phase respons can i use this formula: $arctan(\frac{Im[ 1-2e^{-jqw}]}{Re[1-e^{-jw}+8/9e^{-2*w*j}} $ ?

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson :))) **"Denumerator"** is possibly the **opposite** of numerator, that **ordinary** people should be calling **Denominator** :)) I've looked up the dictionary and no such as thing as denumerator ever defined...

Comment: Denumerator and Remunerator? :-D