# Extremely low frequency filters

Tags: digital-filters

I have a data acquisition board(A/D+Digital Signal Processor) and I want to check if a digital high-pass filter(implemented in DSP) at an extremely low cut-off frequency(0.05Hz) is actually working.

If this was a frequency I could generate with a signal generator it'd be easy to check, but 0.05Hz is too low and I can't generate it. How do engineers check this kind of filters?

Comment: this sounds to me like a DC blocking filter.  is that what it's meant to be?

Comment: depending on what the sample rate is, it's likely you're gonna have the so-called "**cosine problem**" with a HPF and a ridiculously low corner frequency.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson What is "cosine problem"?

Comment: [I discuss it a little in this answer.](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16885/how-do-i-manually-plot-the-frequency-response-of-a-bandpass-butterworth-filter-i/16911#16911)  essentially the problem is with $\cos(\omega)$ when $\omega \ll 1$ and $\cos(\omega)$ gets so close to $1$ that, with finite precision, you cannot tell the difference.

Comment: why not measure the step response?

Answer (score 4):

if this is a first-order HPF DC blocking filter, this is the recommendation i have for it in fixed-point, and i think it would be a good idea in floating point, too.

```
while (n<something)
  {
  y[n]   =  x[n]  -  w[n]*( 2^(1-N) );
  w[n+1] =  w[n]  +  y[n]*( (2^(N-1))*(1-p) );
  n = n+1;
  }
```

where `p` is the pole (in the z-plane and inside the unit circle) and $0<1-$`p`$\ll 1$.  `N` is a big integer.  with fixed-point you would perform the `w[n]*(2^(1-N))` multiplication with arithmetic shift right (ASR) or the `(w[n]>>(N-1))` operation.  in float you can just multiply it and that simply changes the exponent in the floating point value.  the constant coefficient `(2^(N-1))*(1-p)` should be precomputed and `N` chosen so that this is between $\frac12$ and $1$.

the -3 dB corner frequency $\omega_0 = 2\pi\frac{f_0}{f_\mathrm{s}}$ (as *normalized* angular frequency) is a function of the pole `p` and is:

$$\begin{align} 
\cos(\omega_0) &= 1 - \tfrac{(1-p)^2}{2p} \\
 &= 2 - \tfrac12 \left(p + \tfrac1p \right) \\
 &= 2 - \cosh(\ln p)
\end{align}$$

the pole `p` is

$$\begin{align}
p \ &= \ e^{\operatorname{arccosh}(2-\cos(\omega_0))} \\
\\
 &= \ 2 - \cos(\omega_0) - \sqrt{\big(2 - \cos(\omega_0)\big)^2 - 1} \\
\\
 &= \ 1 - 2\sin\left(\tfrac{\omega_0}{2}\right) \left(\sqrt{1 + \sin^2\left(\tfrac{\omega_0}{2}\right)} - \sin\left(\tfrac{\omega_0}{2}\right) \right) \\
\end{align}$$

so
$$ 0 \ < \ 1-p \ = \ 2\sin\left(\tfrac{\omega_0}{2}\right) \left(\sqrt{1 + \sin^2\left(\tfrac{\omega_0}{2}\right)} - \sin\left(\tfrac{\omega_0}{2}\right)\right) \ \ll \ 1 $$

and the shift or exponent change `N` is an integer and should be about

$$ N \approx 1-\log_2(1-p) \approx 1 - \log_2(\omega_0) $$

someone can check my math.

this is an [improvement by Tim Wescott](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!original/comp.dsp/lu9FB8vud0s/dW3h8vljCgAJ) to my [DSP guru trick](https://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/92774-2.php).  it deals with both the cosine problem and the limitations of fixed point arithmetic.

---

latest thinking:  i am not sure, but this might work fine for floating-point operation `x`, `y`, and `w` are all single-precision floats (double-precision floats should be no prob).  `(1-p)` is a coefficient calculated in advance and is very close to zero.

```
while (n<something)
  {
  y[n]   =  x[n]  -  w[n]*(1-p);
  w[n+1] =  w[n]  +  y[n];
  n = n+1;
  }
```