# How to design a good IIR smoothing filter?

Tags: matlab, filter-design

I need to design a smooting filter for computing the envelope of a signal. My specs in Matlab are

```
fs      = 44100;                    % Sampling frequency of 44100 Hz
fpass   = 2;                        % Passband edge frequency of 2 Hz
Wp      = fpass / (fs/2);           % Calculate normalized passband frequency
fstop   = 5;                        % Stopband edge frequency of 5 Hz
Ws      = fstop / (fs/2);           % Calculate normalized stopband frequency
Rp_lin  = 0.0001;                   % Max. passband ripple of 0.0001
Rp      = 20 * log10(1+Rp_lin);     % Calculate stopband ripple in dB
Rs      = 10;                       % Min. stopband attenuation of 10dB

%%                      Design the elliptic lowpass filter

% Calculate the order of the elliptic lowpass filter

[N, W] = ellipord(Wp, Ws, Rp, Rs); 

% Calculate the coefficients of the elliptic lowpass filter via Bilinear Transformation

[b_ellip_lp, a_ellip_lp] = ellip(N, Rp, Rs, W, 'low');

% Convert the filter coefficients to second-order sections 

[sos_ellip_lp, g_ellip_lp] = tf2sos(b_ellip_lp, a_ellip_lp); 

%% Distribute the gain equally over the sections
[N_sos, ~] = size(sos_ellip_lp);

sos_ellip_lp(:,1:3) = sos_ellip_lp(:,1:3) * (g_ellip_lp^(1/N_sos));


%% Normalize the coefficients 

sos_ellip_lp = sos_ellip_lp / max(max(abs(sos_ellip_lp)));

%% Plot the 16-bit coefficients of the Elliptic low pass

% Quantize the coefficients for plotting

sos_ellip_lp_16bit = round(sos_ellip_lp * 2^(16-1));

figure(1)
freqz(sos_ellip_lp_16bit);
title('16-bit Elliptic low-pass filter');
```

I am designing an Elliptic filter with ellip. At first the gain is massive

[image]

After gain distribution over all biquads, it looks better.

[image]

After quantizing to 16 bit, I get a 10 dB gain!

[image]

I mean, I can just apply gain correction by trial and error. The filter is not adaptive and thus I can work with it. I would nevertheless like to not have these gain jumps. Filters for higher frequencies did not seem to have this issue.

Comment: Where are your poles and zeros before quantizing ? Where are they after quantizing?

Comment: Ah, the quantization error. Sure... We learned about this. I have indeed not checked and will do that first thing next morning.

Comment: @neolith If by "gain jumps" you mean over-/under-shoots, then elliptic is certainly not the way to go. If a smooth response is needed, try a Thiran, or Gaussian, but then your attenuation will suffer. But, if it's the envelope you're after, a Hilbert transformer might do wonders.

Comment: I will try another filter then. I was given the advice not to use the Hilbert transform by an experienced colleague, because it wouldn’t produce a usable envelope for a guitar signal.

Comment: @neolith Guitar is a different beast, true. Not only you'll need a large order, but because of the low frequencies you'll get *only* the envelope, but what you want (I presume) is a *filtered* version, a sort of a smoothed out peak detector. In that case, use a relatively low-Q filter, a compromise between overshoots and attenuation, since Thiran doesn't attenuate very well (but that's up to you to find out based on your data). BTW, use `@` to notify users when you're replying to them (use `<TAB>` to cycle between names).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Why do I need a large order? I was trying to keep it as low as possible for processing speed. Yes, I want a (sort of) peak detector. The filtered square actually sounds better than the absolute. By calculating it this way I can also experiment with it a little. For a Thiran filter I would have to install the Communications toolbox. At least an Elliptic filter is possible. Chebyshev and Butterworth have a nominator of 0 after quantizing.

Comment: @neolith I was referring to the order of a HT: for 44.1 KHz and an assumed min. 100 Hz lowest freq. you'll need a large order. You don't need any toolbox, just use Thiran's [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/cd84/b18a454fd04a7bfcd1995ddb8c4c6927cc87.pdf). What did you mean by "nominator": numerator (N/d), or denominator (n/D)? Again, if you need as little overshoot as possible, you need low-Q filters. Anything higher than Bessel (Thiran) will give you overshoots. Gaussian is even better, but worse attenuation. If you don't have a choice, use Butterworth.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I meant numerator... I already tried butterworth. Doesn't seem to be possible. I need to filter out everything above 5-10 Hz actually because this is an automatically generated LFO for an effect. It is not easy it seems.

Comment: @neolith You're running into a different problem here: the poles are very close to the origin and there is a numeric limitation that you need to circumvent. There are answers to this, already, but I can't find them.

Comment: Yes, but I am running out of time. I think I will just stick to the gain correction for now. It doesn't sound bad.

Comment: Nah, this is never going to work with 16-bit coefficients. Guess I will have a look at the Bessel filter

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I don't understand anything when reading this paper, but thank you for the hint.

Comment: @neolith [This is the link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/16911/17189). And for Thiran: $$H(z)=\left[\frac{\left( 2 N\right) \operatorname{!}}{N\operatorname{!}} \frac{1}{\prod_{i=N+1}^{2 N}{\left. 2 \tau+i\right.}} \frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^{N}{\left. {{\left( -1\right) }^{k}} \begin{pmatrix}N\\
k\end{pmatrix}\, \prod_{i=0}^{N}{\left. \frac{2 \tau+i}{2 \tau+k+i}\right.} {{z}^{k}}\right.}}\right]$$