# How to implement the discrete Butterworth

Tags: butterworth

I'm trying to implement the Butterworth filter as a high pass filter inside a function, where every time stip a measurement will be passed (inside this function I do have buffers for storing the data).

However, I'm using the Matlab built-in function `butter` to calculate the coefficient. The problem is the filtered signal starts to diverge.

I can tell that this diverge comes because of the discretization but is there any way to solve this issue without high complexity?

Comment: We can't really tell what's happening without looking at your code and a lot more details

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to tell us: are you calculating the coefficients in the Laplace domain then translating them to the z domain, or are you generating the coefficients directly in the z domain?  If you're translating, what transform?  What is your filter order?  Are you realizing the filter as a cascade of 2nd-order sections, or as one giant high-order filter?  What algorithm are you using to realize your filter?  Personally, I don't look at code unless I can help it, so if, in addition to posting your code, you also post your filter coefficients in the z domain, that will help.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I found out that my implementation is true and the problem is caused when I have a really small cut-off frequency (10^-4)

Comment: @jon You're running into numerical problems, see [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/16911/17189) for some workarounds. But if your poles are reeealy close to the origin, you're asking for trouble, unless you have GMP or similar.

Comment: Yes it is a numerical problem :(

Comment: jon, you're having a  numerical problem computing coefficients for a high-pass filter (HPF) with a very low cut-off frequency (relative to Nyquist).  Have you tried using the formulae at the [Audio EQ Cookbook](https://webaudio.github.io/Audio-EQ-Cookbook/audio-eq-cookbook.html)? Use that and then use this trig identity: $$ 1 - \cos(\omega) \ = \ 2 \sin^2 \left( \frac{\omega}{2} \right)  $$ and re-jigger your coefficient formulae.  I think you'll have less trouble with numerical probs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it sounds really helpful