# can I calculate freq response generically from filters?

Tags: frequency-response

I'd like to display the freq response of a Sallen Key filter type (in the specific case, this simple [resonant filter](https://www.musicdsp.org/en/latest/Filters/29-resonant-filter.html)).

on biquad, for example, I calculate magnitude and phase from zeros and poles, such as (in cpp):

```
// zeros
std::complex<double> resZeros(0.0, 0.0);
resZeros += mCoefficients.mA0 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -0 * freq * k2PI));
resZeros += mCoefficients.mA1 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -1 * freq * k2PI));
resZeros += mCoefficients.mA2 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -2 * freq * k2PI));

// poles
std::complex<double> resPoles(0.0, 0.0);
resPoles += 1.0 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -0 * freq * k2PI));
resPoles += mCoefficients.mB1 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -1 * freq * k2PI));
resPoles += mCoefficients.mB2 * std::exp(std::complex<double>(0.0, -2 * freq * k2PI));

std::complex<double> res = resZeros / resPoles;

// magnitude
float magnitude = (float)std::abs(res);
if (std::isnan(magnitude)) {
    magnitude = 0.0f;
}

// phase
float phase = (float)std::arg(res); // i.e. math.atan2(res.im, res.re)
if (std::isnan(phase)) {
    phase = 0.0f;
}

return std::polar(magnitude, phase);
```

this code is taken from the web :) can I do the same with the filter above? generally, can I do it with different kind of filters?

Comment: For magnitude response of a biquad (which is one thing you're doing), [you can sorta rearrange some of the mathematics to make it numerically a little better behaved](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16885/how-do-i-manually-plot-the-frequency-response-of-a-bandpass-butterworth-filter-i/16911#16911).  For phase, there is something else to work out, but what you should do is work out the phase **change** from the previous plotted point to the current and simply accumulate that phase change.  That will automatically calculate group delay and nicely unwrap the phase.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson but I need response of this https://www.musicdsp.org/en/latest/Filters/29-resonant-filter.html, not the biquad (which I already have the code).

Comment: That example has two states (´buf0´ and ´buf1´) and it's LTI.  So it's a biquad.  With the exception of ´in´, attach a $z^{-1}$ to every variable and solve for the transfer function.  Then you'll know how to apply the biquad frequency response.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson so its not a Sallen Key filter type in your opinion?

Comment: [Sallen-Key is an analog circuit for second-order alalog filter.](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/3-s2.0-B9780128116487000169-f16-15-9780128116487.jpg)  It gives you a "biquad" $H(s)$.  But, even if you emulate the analog filter, you will end up with an $H(z)$ that may also be second order, and that's what I usually mean by a biquad and that's all your code can run.  But you're right, you can run the frequency response of an analog filter on a computer, and your code looks like it.  With $j\omega$ instead of $e^{j\omega}$.

Comment: But that resonant filter from Paul Kellet that you pointed to, **that's** a digital filter with an $H(z)$.  `buf0` and `buf1` get defined in terms of their previous values.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson: I'll do per step :) First of all, how would you convert the normalized freq used on that filter (0 to 1) to hz? Can't find a correct map function :O It seems 1000 hz is 0.14? Mmm... any clue? Can be evaluated?

Comment: It *can* be evaluated if I work on it a little.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson maybe make sense open a separated question for this?

Comment: Sure, put that Paul Kellet filter in a question.  I'll work it out.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the frequency response from the poles and zeros in continuous time  (Laplace), write out the transfer function, $H(s)$, as the numerator (zeros) divided by the denominator (poles) and simply replace $s$ with $j\omega$, since the frequency response is the transfer function with $s$ restricted to be the $j\omega$ axis:

$$H(s) = \frac{(s-z_1)(s-z_2)(s-z_3)\ldots}{(s-p_1)(s-p_2)(s-p_3)\ldots} $$

With $z_1$, $z_2$, etc referring to the zero locations on the complex s-plane, and $p_1$, $p_2$, etc referring to the poles.

$$H(j\omega) = \frac{(j\omega-z_1)(j\omega-z_2)(j\omega-z_3)\ldots}{(j\omega-p_1)(j\omega-p_2)(j\omega-p_3)\ldots} $$

This is plug and chug with complex numbers, so multiply it out and then calclulate the magnitude and phase as a function of frequency, which is the frequency response.

For discrete time (Z-transform), it is the same process, except the frequency response is the transfer function in z, $H(z)$, with $z$ replaced with $e^{j\omega}$ with $\omega$ extending from $0$ to $2 \pi$ (the unit circle):

$$H(z) = \frac{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)\ldots}{(z-p_1)(z-p_2)(z-p_3)\ldots} $$

$$H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{(e^{j\omega}-z_1)(e^{j\omega}-z_2)(e^{j\omega}-z_3)\ldots}{(e^{j\omega}-p_1)(e^{j\omega}-p_2)(e^{j\omega}-p_3)\ldots} $$

Here's a very simple and graphical demonstration for a first order single pole continuous time RC low pass filter:

The RC filter results in a single real pole in the left half plane at $s=-\frac{1}{RC}$.

The transfer function for this is: $$H(s) = \frac{1}{s-p_1} = \frac{1}{s+1/(RC)}$$

Graphically on the s-plane we have a ratio of phasors where the numerator is always $1/angle{0}$ and the denominator $s-p_1$ with $s=j\omega$ starts off at DC when \omega=0 to be a phasor with magnitude $1/(RC)$ and angle $0$. This is our starting magnitude referenced by 0 dB on the Bode plot showing the relative magnitude and phase over frequency. As we increase $\omega$ up to the magnitude of the pole (when $s=j (1/(RC))$), the length of the denominator phasor will be $\sqrt{2}$ longer and at an angle of 45°. Given this is in the denominator and the numerator in this case was always 1, this is consistent with a -3 dB magnitude and -45° and is noted as the cutoff frequency.  As we continue to sweep the frequency toward $\infty$ we see that the magnitude of the denominator approaches $\infty$ and the phase approaches +90°, consistent with the magnitude approaching $0$ and phase approaching -90° for $H(j\omega)$.

[image: Filter Example]

Comment: What I would do is replace the symbol for zeros from $z_n$ to $q_n$ so that when you go to digital and $H(z)$, you don't have symbol confusion.

Comment: i just might modify your answer a little.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yes thank you! That has always bothered me but I never had a good idea of how to fix that.